# Accumulator not working properly in parallel stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I made collector who can reduce a stream to a map which has the keys as the items that can be bought by certain customers and the names of customers as values, my implementation is working proberly in sequential stream 
but when i try to use `parallel` it's not working at all, the resulting sets always contain one customer name.

```
List<Customer> customerList = this.mall.getCustomerList();

Supplier<Object> supplier = ConcurrentHashMap<String,Set<String>>::new;

BiConsumer<Object, Customer> accumulator = ((o, customer) -> customer.getWantToBuy().stream().map(Item::getName).forEach(
            item -> ((ConcurrentHashMap<String,Set<String>>)o)
                    .merge(item,new HashSet<String>(Collections.singleton(customer.getName())),
                            (s,s2) -> {
                                HashSet<String> res = new HashSet<>(s);
                                res.addAll(s2);
                                return res;
                            })
    ));

BinaryOperator<Object> combiner = (o,o2) -> {
        ConcurrentHashMap<String,Set<String>> res = new ConcurrentHashMap<>((ConcurrentHashMap<String,Set<String>>)o);
        res.putAll((ConcurrentHashMap<String,Set<String>>)o2);
        return res;
    };

Function<Object, Map<String, Set<String>>> finisher = (o) -> new HashMap<>((ConcurrentHashMap<String,Set<String>>)o);

Collector<Customer, ?, Map<String, Set<String>>> toItemAsKey =
        new CollectorImpl<>(supplier, accumulator, combiner, finisher, EnumSet.of(
            Collector.Characteristics.CONCURRENT,
            Collector.Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH));

Map<String, Set<String>> itemMap = customerList.stream().parallel().collect(toItemAsKey);
```

There is certainly a problem in my `accumulator` implementation or another `Function` but I cannot figure it out! could anyone suggest what should i do ?

Comment: General question: do you really have soooo much data that parallel execution even theoretically makes sense?

Comment: In my needs here i don't have so much data, but i want to practice making  `CONCURENT` `Collectors`

Comment: Why on Earth are you using `Object` as type parameter for all functions, when it is supposed to be `ConcurrentHashMap<String,Set<String>>`, just to perform type casts in every function? Further, don’t specify `IDENTITY_FINISH` when you actual finisher function is not the identity function. Further, do not use a class like `CollectorImpl`; just call `Collector.of(…)` to get a collector.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, I will take them in consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your combiner is not correctly implemented.
You overwrite all entries that has the same key. What you want is adding values to existing keys.

```
BinaryOperator<ConcurrentHashMap<String,Set<String>>> combiner = (o,o2) -> {
        ConcurrentHashMap<String,Set<String>> res = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(o);
        o2.forEach((key, set) -> set.forEach(string -> res.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<>())
                                                          .add(string)));
        return res;
    };
```

Comment: That's absolutoley what I was missing `putAll` from `Map` wasn't the adequate method to use in the combiner, thank you